# Override a Maven filter value with an environment variable or command-line parameter

Tags: maven, environment-variables, maven-3, maven-resources-plugin

We use Maven to build our java projects, with different profiles (testing, staging, production etc). Each profile has a its own filter, declared like :

```
<filters>
    <filter>src/main/filters/filter-${env}.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

(with ${env} being set to the profile name). Each filter contains the values specific to the target environment (mostly configuration parameters).

It's been working great for many years. But, sometimes, **we would like to override one of the values inside this .properties filter file, without modifying the file itself**.

Why? Because it happens very late in the process. We already tagged a version on the SCM, carefully tested it in testing/staging environments, communicated on this version number, and are discovering a wrong parameter value in the production filter when installing in production. It's too late to create a new tag and test again, only for a configuration parameter.

I'd like to find a way to override the value at Maven runtime : either with an environment variable, or by passing some parameters on the Maven command-line.

I suppose it should be possible by extending the maven-resources-plugin ourself, but there might be an easier way?

NB : our build does not only generate a war, but a complete package including its configuration.

Technical environment : Maven 3.3.9, launched by a Jenkins job

Comment: you could use `mvn install "-Dthe.property=the.overriden.value"`

Comment: Shit, I had tested with -DEnv.the.property, but not with -Dthe.property... It works, indeed! I'm ashamed I did not find that myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when executing a maven command, you can override your property by providing it as a system-property.

like `mvn install "-Dthe.property=the overriden value"`

note the " are only needed if the value contains spaces.